# How to clear or rebuild a cached block for a specific user?

Tags: 7, blocks, caching

I have a block with the cache setting `DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_USER`.

I want to clear the cache when a user performs a specific action. I want to clear the cached block only for the acting user, keeping the block cache for all other users.

How can I do that in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This data is stored in the `block_cache` bin under the cid format:

`<MODULE_MACHINE_NAME>:<BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME>:<THEME_MACHINE_NAME>:u.<UID>`

Knowing that, you can build some wrapper function for [`cache_clear_all()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21cache.inc/function/cache_clear_all/7.x) that will delete any arbitrary UID's cached block:

```
function clear_user_block_cache($uid, $module = 'MYMODULE', $block = 'MYBLOCK', $theme = 'MYTHEME') {
  cache_clear_all("$module:$block:$theme:u.$uid");
}
```

You can invoke this function call whenever the user takes the relevant action.

Comment: You can find the module and block machine names by going to the edit page of the block and checking out the URL. Should be `admin/structure/block/manage/<MODULE>/<BLOCK>/configure`.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an exception on cache_clear_all(), make sure you add the table name as second parameter. E.g: cache_clear_all('yourcidstring', 'fromThisDbTable');